# Command line parameter in shell script for python script

Tags: python, shell

Can you please guide me what I am doing wrong here...
The script is only getting the value till the first space in the argument.

```
SENDING_MAIL_LISTENER=$PYTHON" ./rajesh/script.py -s "$SUBJECT_LISTENER" -p "$BODY_LISTENER" -r "$CONTACT_NAME
```

Comment: What is the actual command executed? What does `sys.argv` contain? How do you parse the args? Sorry, but my crystal ball is in repair right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape those double quotes:

```
SENDING_MAIL_LISTENER="$PYTHON ./rajesh/script.py -s \"$SUBJECT_LISTENER\" -p \"$BODY_LISTENER\" -r \"$CONTACT_NAME\""
```